# Why does my CSV write a header after each row?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have an array called `info`, and I want to add each row to the CSV, but I also want to include the header to the top of the file.

I did this:

```
  info.each do |listing|
    CSV.open(csvfile, "a+", write_headers: true, headers: ["Company_Name","Website","Street_Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone","Email"]) do |csv|
      csv << listing
    end
  end
```

But that creates something that looks like this:

[image]

Which is not what I want.

I just want 1 header row at the top.

How do I achieve this?

**Edit 1**

I actually have another nested loop that has the same problem, but I can't simply move it out of the loop -- so how else might I tackle this one?

```
  csvs.each do |csv|
    CSV.foreach(csv, headers: true) do |row|
      #check for presence of valid email
      if (!row['Email'].nil?) && (!row['Email'].include? "no email")
        CSV.open(new_csv, "a+", write_headers: true, headers: ["Company_Name","Website","Street_Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone","Email"]) do |new_csv_row|
          new_csv_row << row
          puts "#{row['Email']} successfully added to #{new_csv}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Move `CSV.open` out of the `info.each` loop.

Comment: Ofcourse! Duh! Stupid me. Perfect, that worked like a charm. Can you just add that as an answer and I will accept it please. Thanks!

Comment: @slowjack2k Actually I have 1 more use case where this happens. I have updated the question, so can you review it and suggest a solution before adding your answer to make sure it is complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one change the loop:

```
CSV.open(csvfile, "a+", write_headers: true, headers: ["Company_Name","Website","Street_Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone","Email"]) do |csv|
  info.each do |listing|
    csv << listing
  end
end
```

For the second:

```
header_written = {} # memorize if header is allready written
csvs.each do |csv|
  ...
  # alternative can be 'write_headers: !File.exist?(new_csv)'
  # but this works only when this file is created here and no empty file exists
  CSV.open(new_csv, "a+", write_headers: !header_written[new_csv], headers: ["Company_Name","Website","Street_Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone","Email"]) do |new_csv_row|
          new_csv_row << row
          puts "#{row['Email']} successfully added to #{new_csv}"
  end
  header_written[new_csv] ||= true
```

*Edit:*  I did recognize just now that `new_csv` is not dynamic. So you can place the second `CSV.open` call also outside the loops or use a simple flag instead of `header_written[]` so you can change it to `header_written = false|true` .

Comment: You can also do `each_with_index` and special case index 0.

Comment: I think index 0 does not work because of the `if`statement.It is not a given that at the first index the csv file is created.

Comment: I mean you'd only have to output headers on index 0, the rest you can ignore. As in: `write_headers: index == 0`

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. But take a look at the `if` statement (#check for presence of valid email). You can pass many csv lines before the new csv file is opened the first time. Maybe no file is written at all.

Comment: True, but that's just bad form. A lazy enumerator and `select` could tidy that all up.

Comment: @tadman maybe, but we don't know the requirements. Maybe `CSV.foreach` reads a large csv file and select would read the hole file into memory. We can only work with what we got. But your free to provide a different version.